# An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in Registration asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, registration

I am attempting at creating a registration page but it's not going as planned. It keeps throwing this error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

In my table I have,

```
    [userid]          INT          NOT NULL,
    [username]        VARCHAR (50) NULL,
```

This is my c# code

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtPassword.Text == txtConfirmPassword.Text)
            {
                string username = txtUsername.Text;
                string password = txtPassword.Text;
                string confirmpassword = txtConfirmPassword.Text;
                string email = txtEmail.Text;

                con.Open();
                String str = "INSERT INTO users (userid, username, password, confirmpassword, email) VALUES(@userid, @username, @password, @confirmpassword, @email)";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@confirmpassword", confirmpassword);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                lblMessage.Text = "OK!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!";
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

I am unsure of how to pass the userid?

**Update**
Needed to set IDENTITY to userid in database. Thanks all

Comment: First off, you need to show the complete error message, and add a try/catch block to your event handler and print message.  What do you mean, "unsure of how to pass the userid?"

Comment: I concur with the try/catch suggestion from OldProgrammer. You'll want to do that anyways in case there are issues on your database server during your 'INSERT' command. Once you see the exception error message caught by the added try/catch block you'll probably see the cause of your error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code tries to write 5 fields but pass only 4 parameters.
The `@userid` parameter is missing from the SqlCommand.Parameters collection.

Now there are two possibilities. If your userid field is an IDENTITY column then you shouldn't pass anything for the `userid` field and the query becomes

```
  String str = @"INSERT INTO users (username, password, confirmpassword, email) 
                VALUES(@username, @password, @confirmpassword, @email)";
```

or, if it is a normal field, you need to add that parameter to your SqlCommand parameter collection.

Comment: it still gives me an error because userid is NOT NULL

Comment: How is defined that field in your database? Has it the IDENTITY set to yes? If yes, then no value should be given, if no, then you should write the query as you have now and provide a parameter with a value for the userid. (However I think that you should put an IDENTITY on this field and let the database engine calculate it for you)

Comment: Using Sql Server Management Studio, go to your table and right click on it. Choose Design, select the UserID field and, in the Column Properties window scroll until you see the Identity Specification group (SQL Server 2014) open it and set to true the IsIdentity cell

Answer (score 1):

First of all; if isIdentity is set to true do not pass the userId param.
Second, even it is mentioned in your connectionstring but you call your table by `CatalogName.dbo.TableName` in your query.

```
"INSERT INTO dbName.dbo.users (username, password, confirmpassword, email) VALUES(@username, @password, @confirmpassword, @email)";
```

Comment: Did you try my suggestion ??

Comment: I have tried without the dbName.dbo.users I just had users and it works thanks